# Local upload to react-avatar-editor

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, input, editor, avatar

I would need a brief hint on how to load a local uploaded file (via ) to react-avatar-editor. 
I suppose I have to pass something related to FileReader as a prop.image to , but looking to the source code I didn't figure it out.